# Can I use two feats affecting unarmed strike at the same time?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, stacking, unarmed-combat

Is there anything preventing a character from using, for example, [Stunning Fist](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/stunning-fist-combat/) on the same attack as he uses [Befuddling Strike](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/befuddling-strike-combat/),  [Perfect Strike](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/perfect-strike-combat/) (with a Ki Focus weapon), [Scorpion Style](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/scorpion-style-combat/), or similar feats?

As far as I can tell from the descriptions the only limit on them is that you can only use each once per round, or in the case of Scorpion Style, as a standard action.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Yes, all of these can be used together, with the exception of Perfect Strike.

Since Scorpion Style is the only feat that has an activation cost, the use of a standard action. Each of the other feats only require that you declare expending a use of them prior to making an attack roll. This makes sense, since Scorpion Style has an unlimited number of uses, while each of the other feats have a limit of only a handful (ha!) of uses per day. This also makes sense when viewed from the perspective of making a Full Attack as a monk, as each of these feats (except Scorpion Style of course) can be activated on any attack as part of a full attack, since they have no activation cost outside of declaring that you're using it.

Since Scorpion Style and Befuddling Strike require an Unarmed Strike *specifically* to be used, and Ki Focus *only* works with a Ki ability, Stunning Fist, or Quivering Palm. They are mutually exclusive with Perfect Strike. Since Ki Focus *specifically* allows Stunning Fist, that *can* be combined with Perfect Strike, so you can use Stunning Fist + Perfect Strike *or* Scorpion Style + Stunning Fist + Befuddling Strike, but not all four.

Comment: I wasn't _actually_ planning on using all four feats at once, those were just for some examples, but good to know none the less.